# Something for Icinga like sensu-metrics-relay

Tags: icinga, metrics

I used to work with Sensu and I was using a plugin called sensu-metrics-relay so I could easily forward some metrics collected using a jenkins plugin called "Metrics Plugin" to graphite.

Now I am using Icinga and I would like to do the same, how can I do that?

Comment: Why did you switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Python tool called [graphios](https://github.com/shawn-sterling/graphios), Icinga 2 has its own [graphite writer](http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/icinga2-features#graphite-carbon-cache-writer).

Comment: Thanks but I am using Icinga 1

Comment: Then look at graphios :)